# NLog : writing multiple lines with the same layout all at once

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, nlog

I'm using NLog in a .NET MVC company project with a shared config file containing the mandatory company layout for each line of log.

The issue is that I want to create several lines of info logs with the same layout but by calling the info() method once. So far I tried something like this :

```
List<string> listContainingTheLines;
var logString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listContainingTheLines);
logger.Info(logString);
```

But the layout is applied only once so I end up with all my lines with only the first one being compliant, like :

```
 02-14-2018 Server A | line of log
 line of log
 line of log
 line of log
 line of log
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want but while still avoiding calling the logging method each time ? I have no choice but to avoid that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why not calling the logger multiple times? What is the expected result?

Comment: I have to log the access of every data displayed on a page (e.g. user XXX has seen the data YYY related to user ZZZ) for all the pages of the platform, and tons of people are using this platform. So basically logging, for example, 20 different data accesses at once instead of doing it separately is a massive increase in performance when we speak about that amount of massive logging. I can simply not call the logger multiple times, it's not an option.

Comment: @Morgoth Not sure what NLog target you are using, but if the target supports batching (File-Target does), then you can just apply the AsyncWrapper and it will automatically write in chunks with little overhead, and very fast. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance